# How to use find ,-exec and cp commands together in ruby code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, terminal, command

I would like to find .plist files recursively in a folder and copy that files into new folder by a single terminal command.

```
find /Users/admin/Desktop/Norton/StaticAnalysis -iname "*.plist" -exec cp {} /Users/admin/Desktop/Test \;
```

This is the command which is working fine in terminal.

But i have to use this command in ruby code.

when i use this in ruby code like

CODE 1:

```
system ("find /Users/admin/Desktop/Norton/StaticAnalysis -iname \"*.plist\" -exec cp {} /Users/admin/Desktop/Test \;")
puts $?.success?
```

OUTPUT IS:

```
find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"

false
```

CODE 2:

```
system ("find /Users/admin/Desktop/Norton/StaticAnalysis -iname \"*.plist\" -exec cp {} /Users/admin/Desktop/Test \;");
end
puts $?.success?
```

OUTPUT IS:

```
siva.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

So please help me how to use this in ruby code.

Comment: Try `\\;` in the command. You need the `\` to make it to the shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
system ("find ... -exec ... \;")
```

ruby is interpreting the `\;` within double quotes as just `;`. You need to double the backslash

```
system ("find ... -iname \"*.plist\" -exec ... \\;")
```

Or use different outer quotes, which means you don't have to escape the inner quotes

```
system %q{find ... -iname "*.plist" -exec ... \;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with [FileUtils](http://apidock.com/ruby/FileUtils) module (fileutils.rb)?

It has namespace for several file utility methods for copying, moving, removing, etc.